# How to filter an Access datasheet form based on fields of datasheet and subdatasheet

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I have an Access DB, along with tables and forms.
In one table I have customers and in a second table as a subdatasheet on the first table I have tags.
I have created a form which shows the customer list along with the subdatasheet which displays all the tags that a customer has.
I would like to filter based on a field of the main datasheet, and on the subdatasheet for a tag.

E.g. where customer_name = "Peter" and tag ="Neighbor"
I saw this code but when trying to use it fails.
[Filter on Subdatasheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450884/filter-on-subdatasheet/73951435#73951435)

When trying Set mainDS = Me.Controls(dataSheetName).Form where do I find the datasheetName?
I tried entering Form Name, Table Name, I searched in form properties but didn't manage to find a solution.

Comment: dataSheetName would be name of subform container control.

Comment: on which property I find this name? and on which do I find the subform datasheet name? Because I never remember naming any of these.

Comment: I refer to these on the previous post/question Me.Controls(dataSheetName).Form , mainDS.Controls(sdsheet).Form

Comment: You find on the Name property of the subform container control. By default Access will assign the container control same name as the object (table, query, form, report) it holds. I always name the container different from the object.

Comment: Correction, Access assigns the same name if form is dragged onto main form. This will establish a subform container control holding that form. If you drag the Subform/Subreport container control from Design tab it will be named like Child0.

Comment: I can't figure it out. mainDS = Me.Controls(dataSheetName).Form

Comment: I looked at the sample code again. It is not making sense to me. If `mainDS` is supposed to be a variable for main form, then it should not be Set to the subform. And there is no explanation of how this code is triggered - datasheets cannot show command buttons so what event is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it sounds like you are new to Access and you  should review table normalization.
Everything starts with a normalized table structure.  Unfortunately you are starting with the relatively difficult **Many to Many Relationship**.  Each Customer can have many tags which is a One to Many Relationship, but there wouldn't be much point to comparing customers unless they could have the same tags, which means each tag can have many customers as well.  For example, create your tables with the corresponding primary and foreign keys and tell access about the relationhip by hitting the ribbon and selecting the relationships tool:

[image]
The raw data in the CustomersTags table is what you are interested in, but it is not userfriendly

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   CustomerTagID    |     CustomerID     |       TagID        |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |                  1 |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |                  3 |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 |                  2 |                  3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 |                  2 |                  4 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 |                  2 |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  6 |                  3 |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  7 |                  2 |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  8 |                  3 |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                  9 |                  2 |                  2 |
```

This is why we use forms for entering and viewing the data.  For speeds sake select CustomersTags and hit create table:

[image]

This is not user friendly so we don't show primary keys and replace (right-click and select change to) all the i'ds with user friendly combo-boxes.  I also change the forms format to Data sheet.

[image]

I continue making the form prettier and add two unbound combo boxes to the header to filter the form with.  You can do this with listboxes or checkboxes, or etc as well.  For instance a multi-select list box so you can select multiple tags.  In all cases you just set the forms filter

[image]

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
'select the combobox afterupdate property to get these events
'you can use macro's if you want
'the exact code is very dependent on things like whether you have default values.  I just show the most necessary case
Private Sub cmbCustomer_AfterUpdate()
If (IsNull(Me.cmbCustomer) Or IsNull(Me.cmbTag)) Then
'do nothing
Else
'filter the forms record source
Me.filter = "(CustomerID = " & Me.cmbCustomer & ") AND TagID = " & Me.cmbTag
Me.FilterOn = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmbTag_AfterUpdate()
If (IsNull(Me.cmbCustomer) Or IsNull(Me.cmbTag)) Then
'do nothing
Else
'the filter is just the WHERE PART of an sql statement without the where
Me.filter = "(CustomerID = " & Me.cmbCustomer & ") AND TagID = " & Me.cmbTag
Me.FilterOn = True
End If
End Sub
```

Next, I switch the forms format to continuous forms and continue prettyifying because to my surprise the datasheet format was blocking setting the filter string.

[image]

[image]

Here is some guidance for making comboboxes, comboboxes are used for displaying userfriendly values instead of IDs.  For instance instead of displaying the raw CustomerID we display the Customer_name but the value in the combobox is the CustomerID.  The unbound combobox's value is the CustomerID corresponding to the user friendly Customer_Name the user selects.  Whether the combobox is bound or unbound you set them up in the same way.  Select a bunch of columns from some table or query then declare how many columns you are showing and their width.  To hide a column set it's width to 0.  The order of the columns determines the order of the numbers.  I bound to the tables and both tables go ID then user friendly description so column-widths is 0,1

[image]

This example allows selecting impossible combinations of Customer and tag which will cause an error.  One way to avoid this would be to set the rowsource of the alternate combobox when you choose a value on the first.  For instance, when you pick a customer you restrict the tags which can be selected in the next combobox.  This is cascading comboboxes:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmbCustomer_AfterUpdate()
'it helps to use the query designer to get the sql right
Me.cmbTag.RowSource = "SELECT Tags.TagID, Tags.FriendlyDescription" & _
" FROM Tags INNER JOIN (Customers INNER JOIN CustomersTags ON Customers.CustomerID = CustomersTags.CustomerID)" & _
" ON Tags.TagID = CustomersTags.TagID WHERE (((CustomersTags.CustomerID)= " & Me.cmbCustomer & "))"
Me.cmbTag.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmbTag_AfterUpdate()
Me.filter = "(CustomerID = " & Me.cmbCustomer & ") AND TagID = " & Me.cmbTag
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.cmbCustomer.SetFocus
Me.cmbTag.Visible = False 'quick and dirty reset 'can't invis a focused control
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this extended answer and suggestions. I actually have already created the tables you refer (well some different names). I already have a form that displays customers in a datasheet and their tags in the sub datasheet. this is for viewing only as there is already a form to create or edit the customer along with adding tags. The only problem was filtering as I mentioned on the first post. for example I want a way that will filter the list with tags as well as some fields from the main customer table so I can filter both of them together.

Comment: So i tried the original previous suggestion with no luck. Currently however I have a workaround of changing the recordset to a query which filters the table based on the tags needed and then the user manually applies one filter more on the column itself.